# React Native Schedule Local Notification Best Practices

Tags: react-native, android-notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm building an app with React Native and handling local notifications with https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

The problem is, When I research about scheduling local notifications, I believe there is a limit for that. My applications purpose is about sending notifications so I need to send 10-15 of them in a day. What is the best practice for that with React Native ?

Should I somehow schedule some events for scheduling local notifications or should I use some remote push notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit on scheduling local notifications. I'm not sure there is limit or not but you can send 10-15 of notifications in a day using this library because I'm using it in that way.

Important thing is that you should set each notification's `id` (in case of ios `userInfo`) and it should be different each other.

Comment: The id property is optional, default value is already unique which is autogenerated

Comment: The problem is I may send 50-100 notifications a day based on user preferences